# how to get one tables value with the other tablels's column relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, function, model, relation

I have two tables in my Laravel project: `teacher_subject` and `subject`. The `teacher_subject` table has three columns: `id`, `teacher_token` and `subject_token`. And the subject table has three columns: `id`, `subject_token` and `subject_name`. `teacher_subject` table's `subject_token` referencing the `subject` table's `subject_token`. Now, I want to get the `subject_name` of `subject_token` wherever the `teacher_token` is 1. I want to get it by Laravel's relation method. But, I don't know how to write the function in `teacher_subject` model and controller to get the `subject_name`. Please tell me how to do a many-to-many relation or `hasManyThrough` relation without a third table?

Comment: you can't do a many to many without a pivot table ... also `teacher_subject` is setup like a pivot table already

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
DB::table('teacher_subject')
->select('*')
->join('subject','subject.subject_token','=','teacher_subject.subject_token')
->where('teacher_subject.teacher_token','=',1)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you certainly don't need `hasManyThrough()` as far as I know, `hasMany()` would suffice. The following is a solution with just two tables. Try it out, I'm not entirely sure if that's what you want.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TeacherSubject extends Model
{
    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subject::class, 'subject_token');
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subject extends Model
{
    public function teacherSubjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TeacherSubject::class, 'subject_token');
    }
}
```

Now, you can do the following

```php
$subject = Subject::with('teacherSubjects')->find(1);
dd($subject, $subject->teacherSubjects);
```

Comment: `hasMany` does not require a 3rd (pivot) table, it is one of the inverses of `belongsTo`

Comment: btw, they both can't be `hasMany`